# Can I create a Contacts group in Gmail based on email search criteria?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

If I search "Office" in my Gmail, is there any way to add all of the contacts involved in those emails to a Contacts group?

I have hundreds of contacts I would like to add to a mailing list that I can easily filter with that keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "new" [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/preview) (currently in "Preview"):

1. Search for the contacts you want to add.
2. Select one of them by mousing over the profile picture, which then turns into a checkbox; click it.
3. At the top of the page it'll now say "1 selected" with a down arrow. Click the down arrow and change the selection to "Select all".
4. In the upper right, click the icon for "Change groups". Select the group you want to add them to, or click "New group" at the bottom to create the new group. All the people you selected should now be in the new group.

In the "old" "non-Preview" [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts):

1. Search for the contacts you want to add.
2. At the top and left of the search results is a checkbox with a down arrow. Click the checkbox to select all of the search results.
3. In the "Groups" menu at the top of the page, select the group(s) you want to add them to, or click "Create new" to create the new group. All the people you selected should now be in the new group.